# Firebase Functions / GCP Functions : HTTPS to externally hosted API fails with HPE_HEADER_OVERFLOW

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm running into `HPE_HEADER_OVERFLOW` error conditions when receiving response to `HTTP(s)` post request.

It would appear the response http header size is greater than 8KB.
Node 8+ has introduced this 8KB restriction as part of security measures.

Monkey-patches to influence the acceptable http header size don't appear to work - anymore?
Considering this is the cloud; one can not use the `--max-http-header-size` NodeJs command-line option either ;-)

Can you advise on a workaround or patch for this? (Other than having the external API impl changed)

Kind regards
Fred

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions doesn't provide any access to the nodejs command line used to run your code.  As far as I know, the security restrictions cannot be bypassed, and nothing is likely to change in this respect.  However, you are certainly free to [file a feature request](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) for it.

Comment: Node 13+ will make this configurable on a per request basis, which makes 100% sense : I trust the API I'm calling and it's answers.
This node --max-http-header-size restriction doesn't make sense in my use case.

I could revert to the deprecated node 6, where, I believe, the responses' http header size won't be an issue.

I'd better start looking for the firebase development roadmap I guess ;-)

Thanks Doug!

Comment: node 13 is not available in Cloud Functions, though.  If you want to choose your node version, build an image for Cloud Run instead.

Comment: was hoping to stay away from cloud run solution if possible at all. and i'm hopeful cloud functions will evolve. again, that dev road map is what i should be looking for. cheers!